# Proof verification of $6^n \geq n3^n$

Tags: real-analysis, induction, solution-verification

n is a natural number. Prove $6^n \geq n3^n$ holds for every natural number.

$n = 1:$

$$6 \geq 3 $$

$n \rightarrow n + 1:$

$$6 ^{n+1} = (3*2)^{n+1} = 3^{n+1}2^{n+1} \geq 3^{n+1}(n+1)2\geq 3^{n+1}(n+1) $$

Is my proof correct?

EDIT:
$$2^{n+1} \geq(n+1)2 \text{ because of Bernoulli inequality}$$

Comment: It is a consequence of inequality $2^n\geq n$.

Comment: You could precise why $2^n \geq (n+1)$.

Comment: You need to explain why $ 2^{n+1}\ge (n+1)$

Comment: @alans , hamam_Abdallah,  OP uses $2^{n+1}\geq (n+1)2$, isn't it?

Comment: Because of Bernoulli.

Comment: Avoid writing $n=n+1$: $0\ne 1$! If you absolutely want to write the inductive step with a formula, you can write, say $n\leftarrow n+1$.

Comment: @Bernard Can the arrow also be pointed into the other direction ?

Comment: For computer scientists, it means  ‘$n$ is replaced with $n+1$’. The command for that (in MathJax as well as in latex) is `\leftarrow`.

Comment: @Bernard Could I also use normal implication ? $n \implies n + 1$

Comment: I woudn't write it so. In this case, it's better to write in ordinary language – something like ‘let's show the case $n+1$  follows from  the case $n$’

Comment: umm $0 \ne 1$, but $1 = 0!$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us prove that $$(\forall n\ge 1)\;\; P_n : 2^n\ge n$$

**first step**
$$2^1=2\ge 1 \implies P_1$$

**second step**

Let $ n\ge 1 $ such that $ 2^n\ge n$.

$$2^n\ge n \implies 2^{n+1}\ge 2n$$

$$\implies 2^{n+1}\ge n+ n$$
$$\implies 2^{n+1}\ge n+ 1$$

Now, just replace $$2^n=\frac{6^n}{3^n}$$

Comment: So I need to prove another induction for the primary induction proof to be valid ?

Comment: @BiliDebili Yes, you used a result which need proof.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $6^n\ge n\cdot 3^n$ is true for $n$ and let's prove it for $(n+1)$.

$6^{n+1}=6\cdot 6^n\ge 6\left(n\cdot 3^n\right)=2\cdot 3\left(n\cdot 3^n\right)=2 n\cdot 3^{n+1}\ge (n+1)3^{n+1}$

proved.